# EJB3 code in EAR can't see JPA entities defined in EJB client jar (in /lib) (throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity:")

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0

I have factored my EJB3 code into:

(i) business logic interfaces and POJO entity beans that are used to build the "[EJB client jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484063/using-the-client-jar-in-ejb-3-and-design-patterns)", and

(ii) business logic code which implements the business interfaces and does the JPA with the database.

The deployed platform is JBoss AS7.1 with Hibernate JPA.

The idea being that the *EJB client jar* is the interface which will also be deployed with the *war* or *wars* which access the business logic code. I am deploying the **EJB3** business logic code as an **EAR** with no **WAR** inside (the **WAR** is deployed independently). Thus, the structure of the top-level business logic **EAR** is as follows:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── commons-lang3-3.1.jar
│   └── Users-client.jar
├── META-INF
│   ├── application.xml
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── Users-ejb.jar
```

In my case above, the **Users-client.jar** is the *EJB client jar* (the interface) and the **Users-ejb.jar** is business logic implementation and JPA code.

The structure of the business logic implementation code (**Users-ejb.jar**) is:

```
├── base
│   └── AbstractFacade.class
├── facades
│   ├── PrivateUserDataFacade.class
│   └── UserFacade.class
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   ├── persistence.xml
│   └── postgres-ds.xml
└── utils
    └── JPUtil.class
```

Where the **persistence.xml** contains the following tag:

```
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

However, with the above setup, code in the **Users-ejb.jar** does not recognize the @Entity beans defined the **Users-client.jar** as entities. This is not a *class not found* issue as the code compiles and deploys, rather a 'Not an entity' exception is thrown at runtime.

So, for instance the following test method in class **UserFacade.class**:

```
public String boo(String name)
{                                                                   
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq =
      getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(User.class)); // <-- exception thrown
    List<User> all = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return "boo"+name;
}
```

fails where marked with the trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class entities.User
at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:158)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:136)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:177)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at facades.UserFacade.boo(UserFacade.java:46) [Users-ejb.jar:]
```

What should I do to ensure that classes found in the lib/Users-client.jar are recognized as Entities by my business logic code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define entities in `peristence.xml`

```
  <persistence-unit name="YourUnit">
     <class>com.package.User</class>
     <class>com.package.AnotherEntity</class>
...
```

Comment: Yeap, that does the trick. However, shouldn't the <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> be enough? Or is it on account of the said classes be defined in jar located in the lib folder of the EAR as opposed to being defined in the actual module ?

Comment: When using `exclude-unlisted-classes` set to false, the classess have to be in the same package. However it is better to list the classess either way.

Comment: @siebz0r why would it be better to list them either way? I don't want to have to specify entities, scanning is just fine and I always make sure it works by having my packaging right.

Comment: @ymajoros To be honest, I don't remember, it's been a year ago. ;-) I think I meant for clarity or documentation reasons, maybe even performance.